# Controlling the listbox inside a user control from main form and other user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control that has a listbox inside it. I would like to use this listbox as a message board in my application. So the main form and maybe other user controls in the program are going to send messages for the listbox to display.

I wonder what is the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create method for adding messages to your `MessageBoardControl`:

```
public void AddMessage(string message)
{
    messagesListBox.Items.Add(message);
}
```

Then you can all this method from your form:

```
messageBoardControl1.AddMessage("Hello World");
```